# If $f_t(x) \to 0$ and $x_t \to x$ does $f_t(x_t) \to 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $f_t:H \to H$ for each $t \in [0,T]$ be a map between a Hilbert space $H$. If $f_t(x) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$, and if $x_t \in X$ is such that $x_t \to x$ as $t \to 0$, then under what assumptions can I expect
$$f_t(x_t) \to 0$$ as $t \to 0$?

Is uniform covergence of $f_t(x) \to 0$ on compact subsets enough for this?

Comment: I don't think it is enough, if $f_t(y)=0$ for $y\leq 1/t$ and $f_t(y)=1$ for $y \geq 2/t$ and $x_t = 3/t$ then you get $f_t(x_t)=1$ for every $t$ although $x_t\to 0$ and $f_t(0)=0$ for every $t\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: I guess you need that $f_t$ converge uniformly wrt to the sup norm.

Comment: @Serb do you mean if $\lim_{t \to 0}\sup_{x \in A}f_t(x) = 0$? For all $A \subset H$? Can I get away with $A$ compact?

Comment: well maybe not that strong :). If $A$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $f_t$ is continuous on $A$ for every $t$ and $\lim_{t\to 0} \sup_{z\in A} \|f_t(z) -f(z)\| = 0$ for some $f$ continuous on $A$ such that $f(x)=0$, then $f_t(x_t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0$.

Comment: It's an argument of the form $||f_t(x_t)|| \leq || f_t(x_t)-f(x_t)||+||f(x_t)-f(x)||$. But maybe there is a possibility to have it under weaker conditions... I dunno

Comment: When you write $f_t(x)\to0$ do you mean that $f_t$ converges to the zero function, or just that $f_t$ converges at $x$ to $0$?

Comment: @s.harp I mean it converges to the zero function. For all $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform convergence on bounded sets is enough:

For if $f_t\to0$ uniformly on bounded sets, you've got for any bounded set $A$ and any $\epsilon$ a value $t'_{(A,\epsilon)}$ so that $t<t'$ implies $\|f_t\|_A<\epsilon$. Now since $x_t\to x$ you've got a $t''$ so that if $t<t''$ the distance between $x_t$ and $x$ is smaller than $1$. So if you take $A=B_1(x)$ then for $t<\min(t'_{(A,\epsilon)},t'')$ you've got $x_t\in A$ and $|f_t(x_t)|≤\|f_t\|_A<\epsilon$.

Now if you are looking at a *sequence* $x_n$ and $f_{t_n}(x_n)$ with $t_n\to0$, then uniform convergence on compacta is enough. Uniform convergence on compacta is also enough if you have that $t\mapsto x_t$ is continuous in *some neighbourhood of $0$*.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So in your first part, you say what I want holds given the uniform convergence on bounded sets. I don't really understand your second part.. under a stronger assumption (uniform boundedness on compact sets) you prove a weaker result, isn't it??

Comment: @PostName uniform convergence on compact sets is much weaker than uniform convergence on bounded sets. Every compact set is bounded (but not every bounded set is contained in a compact set!). Here we relax the strength of $f_t\to0$ but make the $x_t\to x$ condition stronger so the result stays the same.

Comment: Thanks, one final question. The second part, you are saying if $f_t \to 0$ uniformly on compact sets, and if $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$, then there is sequence $t_n$  with $t_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ such that $f_{t_n}(x_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Is that right? I think it is a weaker result that the desired one if I'm correct.

Comment: If $f_t\to0$ uniformly on compacta and $x_n\to x$, then for any sequence $t_n\to0$ you have $f_{t_n}(x_n)\to0$. This result is not comparable with the previous, since while you have a stronger condition on how you are going to the point $x$ via $x_t$, you have a weaker condition on how $f_t\to0$.

Comment: I don't see why $x_n \to x$ is a stronger condition than $x_t \to x$. If $x_t \to x$ then $\hat x_n := x_{(1/n)} \to x$ as $n \to \infty...$

Comment: Statement A is weaker than B: (A) For every sequence $x_n\to x$ and any $t_n\to0$ we have $f_{t_n}(x_n)\to0$. (B) For every map $t\mapsto x_t$ so that $x_t\to x$ as $t\to0$ we have $f_t(x_t)\to0$ as $t\to0$. A is implied by B but not the other way around. Since the conclusions are the same, this means the condition in A is more of a restriction on what kind of situations can be considered (stronger).

Comment: @s.harp Could you give a hint why continuity of $t \mapsto x_t$ + uniform on compacta would suffice?

Comment: @25Chars Call the map $t\mapsto x_t$ $\gamma$. If $\gamma$ is continuous in some neighbourhood$[0,\kappa)$, then $K:=\gamma([0,\kappa/2])$ is compact since it is the image of a compact set under a continuous mapping. You have $\|f_t\|_K\to0$ and for any $t<\kappa/2$ you have $|f_t(x_t)|≤\|f_t\|_K\to0$.